# Serve specific javascript for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I'm introducing a menu that includes mouseover elements and as such isn't suitable for touchscreens. Is there a way to instruct mobile devices to load different javascript in a similar fashion to CSS media queries?

For the record the menu is a little like the following:

http://www.webchief.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-dropdown-menu/finishedMenu.html

And no it wasnt my choice to implement this specific behavior..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries to set a specific element's appearance (i.e. display: none/block) and then run a conditional on that...

e.g.

```
if($('#myElement').is(':visible')){
    // run code
}
```